# UIView changes width after switching orientation to landscape?

Tags: iphone, ipad, resize, orientation

I got a UIView with 2 subviews. The UIView is set to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth. Now when it enters layoutSubviews it resizes the frames of the subviews relative to the UIView like so:

```
rect.size.width  = self.frame.size.width - rect.origin.x - textLabel.frame.origin.x;
```

But a problem occurs in landscape mode cause in portrait mode the self.frame.size.width (and bounds for that matter) respond 768 at start and 788 after it's done rotating. Meaning when it rotates it seems to add 20pixels which I assume is the status bar.

When I hard code 768 it all works as expected. But I don't want that of course. I could store the initial state into a var and use that but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Greetings,

in my application I have been facing the same Problem. To solve it I simply used the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`method to resize the View when the device is rotated.
`self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);`

Hope this will help.